# Do a Re-Build During a Re-Shape?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm

On my Linux software RAID 6 array, I'm currently mid-reshape and 2 drives have been marked as failed.  I've swapped them out and added new ones to the array, which are currently marked as spares.  The re-shape has a *lot* of time left and I'm worried that a third failure will happen during that time and kill the whole array.  Is there a way to maybe pause the re-shape and do a re-build onto the spares?

Comment: Increasing the speed of the reshape (I don't have a full answer for you) can be done by killing off everything else - I find mdadm runs a lot faster if I temporarily disable most of the services my server runs while it rebuilds or reshapes an array.

Comment: @Xyon: Everything's shut off and the file system is unmounted, but even at that I'm still looking at 4 days of pegged disk access for the re-shape.  20 2-TB drives.